# Svg icon in marker in TomTom maps

Tags: tomtom

I was working on a project using TomTom maps on WebSdk. I am currently using `png` image for markers and I was wondering if there is anyway we could use `svg` icon in the marker instead of an image?

Answer (score 1):

Try that way:

```
var svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><svg height="100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>';
var iconUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg);
tomtom.L.marker([51.75939,19.44856], {
  icon: tomtom.L.icon({
    iconUrl: iconUrl,
    iconSize: [30, 34],
    iconAnchor: [15, 34]
  })
}).addTo(map);
```